# Implementing Bezier Curves

Tags: animation, interpolation, bezier

I am trying to implement Bezier Curves for an assignment. I am trying to move a ball (using bezier curves) by giving my function an array of key frames. The function should give me all the frames in between the key frames ... or control points ... but although I'm using the formula found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)... it is not really working :s

her's my code:

```
  private void interpolate(){
      float x,y,b, t = 0;
      frames = new Frame[keyFrames.length];
      for(int i =0;i<keyFrames.length;++i){   
         t+=0.001;
         b = Bint(i,keyFrames.length,t);   
         x = b*keyFrames[i].x;
         y = b*keyFrames[i].y;
         frames[i] = new Frame(x,y);     
      }
  }

private float Bint(int i, int n, float t){
  float Cni = fact(n)/(fact(i) * fact(n-i));
  return Cni * pow(1-t,n-i) * pow(t,i);
}
```

Also I've noticed that the frames[] array should be much bigger but I can't find any other text which is more programmer friendly

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Processing]http://processing.org/ it is Java based, however the Frame class and KeyFrame class are all my creation. (they're nothing really just an x, y position and a time field which I'm not using in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got What I needed! Here's what I did:

```
private void interpolate() {    
  float t = 0;
  float x,y,b;
  for(int f =0;f<frames.length;f++) {      
    x=0;
    y=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<keyFrames.length; i++) {       
      b = Bint(i,keyFrames.length-1,map(t,0,time,0,1));   
      x += b*keyFrames[i].x;
      y += b*keyFrames[i].y;
    }    
  frames[f] = new Frame(x,y); 
  t+=partialTime;     
}
```

}

> 

```
private void createInterpolationData() {
     time = keyFrames[keyFrames.length-1].time -
     keyFrames[0].time;
     noOfFrames = 60*time;
     partialTime = time/noOfFrames;
     frames = new Frame[ceil(noOfFrames)];  
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the code in the original question, and has all the same drawbacks as I mentioned in my answer apart from #3 (which it fixes). But if it meets your needs, fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of things that don't look quite right here.

1. Doing it this way, your interpolation will pass exactly through the first and last control points, but not through the others. Is that what you want?
2. If you have lots of key frames, you're using a very-high-degree polynomial for your interpolation. Polynomials of high degree are notoriously badly-behaved, you may get your position oscillating wildly in between the key frame positions. (This is one reason why the answer to question 1 should probably be no.)
3. Assuming for the sake of argument that you really *do* want to do this, your value of `t` should go from 0 at the start to 1 at the end. Do you happen to have exactly 1001 of these key frames? If not, you'll be doing the wrong thing.
4. Evaluating these polynomials with lots of calls to `fact` and `pow` is likely to be inefficient, especially if `n` is large.

I'm reluctant to go into much detail about what you *should* do without knowing more about the scope of your assignment -- it will do no one any good for Stack Overflow to do your homework for you! What have you already been told about Bezier curves? What exactly does your assignment ask you to do?

EDITED to add:

The simplest way to do interpolation using Bezier curves is probably this. Have one (cubic) Bezier curve between each pair of key-points. The endpoints (first and last control points) of each Bezier curve are those keypoints. You need two more control points. For motion to be smooth as you move through a given keypoint, you need (keypoint minus previous control point) = (next control point minus keypoint). So you're choosing a single vector at each keypoint, which will determine where the previous and subsequent control points go. As you move through each keypoint, you'll be moving in the direction of that vector, and the longer the vector is the faster you'll be moving. (If the vector is zero then your cubic Bezier degenerates into a simple straight-line path.)

Choosing that vector so that everything looks nice is highly nontrivial, but you probably aren't really being asked to do that at this stage. So something pretty simple will probably be good enough. You might, e.g., take the vector to be proportional to (next keypoint minus previous keypoint). You'll need to do something a bit different at the start and end of your path if you do that.

Comment: And I don't want you to do my homework for me. Basically We have a 
a topic called Animation we where very briefly told about linear interpolation , cubic splines, cutmul rom and bezier curves, Then we where asked to implement them  heh that's all the info I've got.
 
However I'm more inclined to programming rather that math and although the formula found on wikipedia is quite straight forward I didn't quite get what is _t_ exactly ?

Comment: Even maybe some programmer friendly tutorial or something that's all I ask I'm usually proud of my programs and love to take new challenges but I think I've hit my head or something.

Comment: You can think of `t` as a time value, parameterizing motion along the curve. At `t=0` you're at the first control point. At `t=1` you're at the last control point. In between, you move in a way that's governed by the other control points, but don't necessarily (or even usually) pass through any of them.

Comment: If you have an arbitrary sequence of positions and you want to make something that interpolates smoothly between them, then you're looking at some variety of spline interpolation. You can do that with Bezier curves, but there's extra (nontrivial) work involved in choosing the control points: it goes beyond just "implement Bezier curves". (Without knowing exactly what you were told to do, I don't know whether that indicates that it's more than your instructor wants you to do!)

Comment: **Perform the inbetweening using a variety of techniques (linear interpolation,
Catmull-Rom splines and Bezier curves) and evaluate the results.** That is one of the questions in the assignment brief ( the others then are commenting on the implementation and performance, etc ...)

Comment: Hmm, fair enough. Well, if you've had anything in your course materials telling you how to use Bezier curves for inbetweening when all you've got is a bunch of keyframe positions, then you should use that. Otherwise, do something simple like what I described in the edited version of my answer. Have you considered asking your instructor whether you're expected to do anything very sophisticated when choosing what Bezier curves to interpolate along?